# Installing Apache Superset on Heroku gives "relation 'user_attribute' does not exist" erorr

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, heroku, sqlalchemy, apache-superset

I try to install Apache Superset on Heroku (for a week already) with this manual: https://chizurumolorondu.medium.com/setting-up-apache-superset-on-heroku-b547302f600e

The local Superset installation (with pip install) works fine. I followed all steps in the manual. However, when I try to login into Superset (on Heroku) I continuously get the error "relation 'user_attribute' does not exist". Here is a part of my log:

```
2024-01-22T11:39:36.946252+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "user_attribute" does not exist
    2024-01-22T11:39:36.946252+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 2: FROM user_attribute
    2024-01-22T11:39:36.946252+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
    2024-01-22T11:39:36.946253+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2024-01-22T11:39:36.946253+00:00 app[web.1]: [SQL: SELECT user_attribute.welcome_dashboard_id AS user_attribute_welcome_dashboard_id
    2024-01-22T11:39:36.946253+00:00 app[web.1]: FROM user_attribute
    2024-01-22T11:39:36.946253+00:00 app[web.1]: WHERE user_attribute.user_id = %(user_id_1)s]
    2024-01-22T11:39:36.946253+00:00 app[web.1]: [parameters: {'user_id_1': 1}]
    2024-01-22T11:39:36.946253+00:00 app[web.1]: (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

The "superset db upgrade" CLI command, which should create this table in Postgres, does not seem to work. A reason for that could be that the "superset db upgrade" does not apply to the Heroku Postgres but to the SQLite database(?). I could generate the user_attribute table myself, but this again generated errors and it does not seem as a solid solution to me. At present, the Heroku Postgres has the following tables:

[Heroku Postsgres tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahMuk.jpg)

As you can see, there is no table "user_attribute"
Other details that might cause the error:

- I use python-3.9.18 (defined in the runtime.txt file)
- Postgres on Heroku is a 'mini' (heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:mini)
- I use "sslmode=require" in the URL of SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI (located in the superset_config.py)

I checked of course all other postings related to this issue, but none of the (few) solutions seem to solve my problem. Does anyone has an idea how I can make this work and make sure that the correct table structure of Superset is copied to the Heroku Postgres?